# Authentication in spring security but without user and pass only token

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data

I am trying implement security for my app, I need configure the security the mains only using security token, I don´t want use security mean user and password, only security token to **authorization** and create session for **consume my resources api**

How I can configure this for security configuration the my app?

Comment: What's the token?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use spring OncePerRequestFilter for this task

```
//MyFilter.java
public class MyFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private String securityTokenHeader ="token"; 

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String securityToken = request.getHeader(securityTolenHeader);
    if (checkToken(securityTokenHeader)){
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response); //continue
    }
    else{
        logger.error("Not authenticated activity");
        //you can also edit the response object here to inform your client
    }
}
}
```

Configuration file

```
//FilterConfig.java
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean myFilter(){
    MyFilter filter = new MyFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
}
```